# Can black hole experiences Coriolis effect?

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, reference-frames, event-horizon, coriolis-effect

The weather here are thanks to Earth's rotation, so would there be any coriolis effect however tiny occurs when black hole rotates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculations have shown a coriolis term.  [Example:](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.08691)

> In this work, we consider the fluid/gravity correspondence for general rotating black holes. By using the Petrov-like boundary condition in near horizon limit, we study the correspondence between gravitational perturbation and fluid equation. We find that the dual fluid equation for rotating black holes contains a Coriolis force term, which is closely related to the angular velocity of the black hole horizon. This can be seen as a dual effect for the frame-dragging effect of rotating black hole under the holographic picture.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a [Coriolis-like effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lense%E2%80%93Thirring_precession#The_Coriolis_term) due to frame-dragging. A radially infalling geodesic in the Lense-Thirring spacetime will satisfy the equation $$0 = r\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}+2\frac{GJ}{c^2r^3}\frac{dr}{dt}$$ which can be compared to motion subject to the Coriolis force $$0=r\frac{d\phi}{dt^2}+2\omega\frac{dr}{dt}.$$ (see also [Lämmerzahl &  Neugebauer 2001](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-40988-2_3.pdf), who derive it with more rigour and an extra term; see equation 70 and 79).

One can also think about it using [gravitoelectromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism), the formal analogy between electromagnetism and the weak field approximation of GR. In this case the Coriolis-like force is due to the analogy to magnetism: massive objects in motion feel a force at a right angle to their velocity just like charged objects feel a magnetic force at a right angle to their velocity.

Comment: How can their be coriolis force on a featureless surface?The Earth has material on the surface which can bend and move according to the Coriolis Force but how can a black hole experience everything matter experiences like coriolis and tidal? Isn't this something that happens because of something made of matter and not just mass?